# Creating selection from selection in attribute table?

Tags: qgis-3, attribute-table, select-by-attribute

Is it possible to repeat a selection in a QGIS 3.10 attribute table so that it is a selection from the selection (i.e., a subset of the original selection)?

Comment: ArcGIS has the ability to show selected features in the table (default blue), and then manually select from (the term they use is highlight) those in another color (default yellow) and then see these in the map and table and apply some functions to them  while keeping the original selection in place if one chooses and continue to make different highlights from it.  I do miss that functionality in QGIS.  This has come up previously here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/216483/with-qgis-can-you-highlight-a-single-feature-within-currently-selected-features

Comment: You have asked 14 question but never accepted an answer. Why?

Answer (score 6):

In the case of the `Select by location tool`, you can define a spatial criteria to select features only within the already selected features.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Can I make a selection from a selection by just clicking into the Attribute Table of the vector layer?

Answer (score 6):

Use `Filter Current Selection`:

[image]